# Python Telegram pytg post content to a channel

Tags: python, telegram

I am trying to post some messages on a channel using the [pytg](https://github.com/luckydonald/pytg) library which is also using the vysheng telegram-cli. I tried some options like

```
sender.send_msg("ChannelName", "Message")
sender.fwd("ChannelName", msg.id)
```

From these lines I am getting this error message

```
pytg.exceptions.FailException: Error 71: 'RPC_CALL_FAIL 400: CHANNEL_MESSAGES_DISABLED'
```

Searching inside Google/GitHub I did find this [vysheng issue # 1033](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/1033) that mentions that we need to send a post to a channel and not a message. But the pytg help(Sender) does not mention anything similar.

I have looked into the possibility of using a bot or other libraries but it's not really what I want.

Is there somebody familiar with pytg that can direct me in the proper direction?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using the raw command inside [pytg](https://github.com/luckydonald/pytg/blob/54658721521bfa4f0a355689bf2aed5d0603b23c/DOCUMENTATION_manual.md#diversa), I guess there's a better solution out there but for the moment this one works!

```
sender.raw("post @nameOfChannel " + msg.text)
```